# Escaping single quotes while parsing XML file (RSS)

Tags: php, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

I have a XML file that I parse .. I didn't generate the XML ..  I faced a problem while parsing the file ... There is a node that has `'` single quotes .. This generates errors ..

I tried using `addslashes()` and `htmlentities()` when using `simplexml_load_file()` but nothing happened!! .. Is there a way to resolve this and parse the file with the quotes??

```
Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: THE URL:853: parser error : Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding ! Bytes: 0xE2 0x20 0x20 0x6C in /****/parseXML.php on line 7
```

Comment: Did you write your own parser routines? Or are you using PHP's built in parser or some 3rd party library?

Comment: I'm using `simplexml_load_file()` that exists in PHP .. Then I extract the data from it ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you have an encoding problem. The single quotes are likely not the single quote character as found on your keyboard but rather a fancier one generated by a word pressing program. The result is likely that your input file is not UTF-8, but rather another multibyte character set.

You either need to convert the encoding with a text editor to make the file completely UTF-8, or use PHP's [iconv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) to convert from the encoding of the file (probably ISO-8859-1) to UTF-8 encoding and then load it with [simplexml_load_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php).

Comment: Well, as I said, I'm not the creator of the XML, but I just load and parse it .. So is there a way to do that from my side?

Comment: When you said you didn't create it, I didn't realize you meant you have no write access to it but rather it's a remote URL. In that case, load the URL with `cURL` or `file_get_contents(url)`, convert the encoding with `iconv`, then load with `simplexml_load_string`. That will all be done in memory without access to the physical file.

Comment: I tired `file_get_contents` after that `iconv` from ASCII to UTF-8, but I got another error!! `Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: I/O warning : failed to load external entity "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl"`

Comment: You need to use `simplexml_load_string()` instead of `simplexml_load_file()`.

Comment: not working!! Are there any other methods to read the XML file?!!

Comment: Try converting from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 first. Also, if there is an error message associated with it not working, that would be very helpful. It would be even better to edit your original question above with your code to make sure we're on the same page.